# Vue Router working in most components but not toolbar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-material

I'm using Vue along with Vue Material. Here is the structure of my app.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="toolbar">
      <md-toolbar>
        <h1 class="md-title">OATS</h1>
      </md-toolbar>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Using this.$router.push works for all my views that are the result of routing. However, I want to have a logout button in my toolbar, and thus have a function

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'toolbar',
  methods: {
    logout: function () {
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:8081/api/logout').then(function (res) {
        this.$store.commit('updateUser', '')
        this.$router.push('/login/')
      }).bind(this)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

inside my Toolbar.vue. When it hits the router.push, it gives me a this.$router is undefined error. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: You need to call `bind` on the anonymous function, not the promise that is returned from `then`. Or even better, use `res => {}` syntax to automatically bind `this`.

Comment: This did not work. The same error is present when moving the bind or doing the => {} syntax.